# c# dependency Injection with generic Repository which should access attribute of concrete type

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, repository-pattern, typeof

I tried to use dependency injection with ms extension host and use generic Repository Interfaces and classes with concrete entities. In those generic repository classes I tried to access the generic class parameter T and get the concrete entity class. Because I wanted to access attributes of the concrete entity class. T or typeof(T) delivered only the interface of entity and not concrete class.

---

I started a new project, trying to use clean architecture for the first time. For infrastructure layer (postgres/dapper access) I wanted to implement repository pattern. I wrote interfaces for all entities and all interfaces for all repositories.

I wrote some classes with repository pattern, using attributes for table and column names (e.g. "foreign_id") similar like dapper contrib is doing, to map real db names for table and some columns.

```
public interface ImyClassA
{
    long? MyId { get; }

    int ForeignId { get; set; }
    int Cntrl { get; set; }
    string MyText { get; set; }
}

[DbTable("test_myclass_a")]
public class MyClassA :  ImyClassA
{
    
    [DbIgnoreWrite(true)]
    [DbId]
    public long? MyId { get; }
    [DbColumn("foreign_id")]
    public int ForeignId { get; set; }
    public int Cntrl { get; set; }
    public string MyText { get; set; }
}
```

After writing some of these classes I saw that those classes all similar. Therefore I read about generic repository pattern and implemented it.

```
public interface IReadOnlyRepository<T> where T : class
{
    Task<IReadOnlyList<T>> GetAllAsync();
    Task<T> GetByIdAsync(long id);
}


public class GenericReadOnlyRepository<T> : IReadOnlyRepository<T> where T : class
{
    protected readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    protected ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> _sqlstatements = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();
    protected Type classtype;

    public GenericReadOnlyRepository(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        // Injecting Iconfiguration to the contructor of the product repository
        _configuration = configuration;
        classtype= this.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
    }




    public async Task<IReadOnlyList<T>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        var sql = DbHelper.GetSqlSelect(typeof(T));
        
        using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDb")))
        {
            connection.Open();

            var result = await connection.QueryAsync<T>(sql);
            return result.ToList();
        }
    }

    public async Task<T> GetByIdAsync(long id)
    {
        var sql = $"{DbHelper.GetSqlSelect(typeof(T))} WHERE Id = @Id";
        using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDb")))
        {
            connection.Open();
            var result = await connection.QuerySingleOrDefaultAsync<T>(sql, new { Id = id });
            return result;
        }
    }

}
```

DbHelper.GetSqlSelect search in the class for the attributes: DbTable and DbColumn(also DbId) and constructs the correct sql statements - because properties of class (and interface) differs to the postgres database names.
Insert and Update Statements are constructed in a smiliar way in a GenericReadWriteRepository.

Afterwards I tried to use this repository with Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting. (Actually with Dapplo.Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WinForms but this is not important.)

I tried different possiblities but adding concrete repositories to service produced errors.

services.AddScoped<IReadOnlyRepository<ImyClassA>, GenericReadOnlyRepository<MyClassA>>();

Using following code:

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureWinForms<Form1>()
                .ConfigureLogging()
                .ConfigureConfiguration(args)
                .ConfigureSingleInstance(builder =>
                {
                    builder.MutexId = "{CACB6ABE-3F1E-47CA-BA67-4FC5B427D798}";
                    builder.WhenNotFirstInstance = (hostingEnvironment, logger) =>
                    {
                        // This is called when an instance was already started, this is in the second instance
                        logger.LogWarning("Application {0} already running.", hostingEnvironment.ApplicationName);
                    };
                })
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddScoped(typeof(IReadOnlyRepository<>), typeof(GenericReadOnlyRepository<>));
                })
```

worked but GenericReadOnlyRepository delivers for typeof(T) only ImyClassA and not my concrete MyClassA.
Also this.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0] in the constructor: ParosGenericReadOnlyRepository delivers only the interface and not the concrete class (object)
But my attributes to generate the sqlstring are in the concrete class and not in the interface.

Now I'm not sure: isn't it possible to access concrete T (object)types in generic classes, or is the code to add the repository to services wrong?

Doing the whole process without generics, worked (incl. dependency injection) But I don't want to write the whole same code again and again for every entity.

I tried also to inherit concrete repositories (without generic parameter T) from generic repositories but didn't work either.

(This is my first question here, so please consider this - if I made some fault in form of question) In advance - thanks for every try to help me further.

---

Edit:
Reading more about generics and reflection, I have the suspicion that getting the runtime type in a generic class is not possible - because generics only work at compile time? Is this correct?

If this is correct, then I should implement it only with inheritance and without generics. For the Insert method: `Task<int> AddAsync(ImyClassA entity);` this would be possible, because I have the class-object as input. For the Select method: `Task<IReadOnlyList<ImyClassA >> GetAllAsync();` there I do not have any information about which class is returned, so I can not get the type in this method? Would it be better to change it to an out parameter? `Task<int> GetAllAsync(out IReadOnlyList<ImyClassA> data);`

Comment: "because generics only work at compile time? Is this correct?" Yeap